# Python - Работа с файлами. Хэширование

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, хеширование

Задача:

> Скрипт должен считывать текст из файла in.txt, запрашивать у пользователя пароль, который должен быть введен им с клавиатуры. Далее исходный текст хэшируется с использованием алгоритма md5 и записывается в новый файл.

***Комментарий к написанному коду:***

> "Решение все равно нелогичное. Напишите просто, чтобы пароль вводимый пользователем шифровался и записывался в файл."

```
import hashlib as hl
f = open('C:\\abc\in.txt', 'w')
p = 'Zolotie Kupola'
if p == input('Enter the password: ', ):
    h = hl.md5(b'C:\\abc\in.txt')
    f.write(str(h.hexdigest()))
else:
    print('Uncorrect password')
f.close()
```

Comment: Наверно идея задания в том, чтобы запаролить файл, нелогичность комментатор заметил в захардкоривании пароля в коде. Думаю стоит записать в файл хэш и сравнивать его с хэшем вводимого пароля.

Comment: Уточните, так в чем состоит ваш вопрос? или надо записать решение за вас и зачет тоже за вас получить?

Comment: @Kromster в чем мое решение оказалось нелогичным?

Answer (score 2):

Давайте по шагам:

```
import hashlib as hl

# Скрипт должен считывать текст из файла in.txt
with open(r'C:\abc\in.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# ...запрашивать у пользователя пароль, который должен быть введен им с клавиатуры
password = input('Enter the password: ')

# Содержимое файла + введенный пароль
data = text + password

# В хеш попадает байтовая строка
h = hl.md5(data.encode('utf-8'))

# Сохранение в новый файл
with open(r'C:\abc\out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(h.hexdigest())
```

---

**PS.**
Для ввода секретной информации можно использовать [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html).

Для этого импортируйте и используйте вместо `input`:

```
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass('Enter the password: ')
```

Comment: Вместо `input` для ввода пароля можно использовать `getpass`, тогда он даже на экране показываться не будет.

Comment: @Avernial, спасибо, добавил пример с getpass